# Como usar Named Parameters no $http do AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, http

Existe alguma maneira de usar `named parameters` no método `$http` do Angular?

Com `ngResource` é possível fazer isto:

```
var User = $resource('/path/to/user/:id');
$scope.user = User.get({id: 1}, function() {
   $scope.user.name = $scope.user.first_name + ' ' + $scope.user.last_name;
});
```

Alguém conhece uma maneira de fazer isto no método `$http`?

Answer (score 0):

`$http.get('/someUrl').`

URL = `'api/controler/action?parameter1=xxx&parameter2=xxx'` - no caso de uma webapi2, isso depende do tipo de servidor que você está consumindo.

```
$http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
      then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

> The response object has these properties:
>
> data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
>
> status – {number} – HTTP status code of the
>
> response. headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
>
> config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate
>
> the request. statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.